# android cursorindexoutofbounds index 0 requested

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-cursor

I am trying to return a row (one per table) from the table of whatever fRate is equal to (a currency symbol, USD, JPY, etc) and then convert the column from that row to a float. Whenever spinner2 is set to something aside the default selection (which is AUD, the first table in my db) I get the error.

```
    Button convert = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    convert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
            DataBaseHelper dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context);
            try {
                dbHelper.createDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            dbHelper.openDataBase();
            db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

            String lRate = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String fRate = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();       
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+fRate+" ", null);
            c.moveToNext();
            Float cfRate = c.getFloat(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(lRate));
                c.close(); 



            answer.setText(String.valueOf((Float.parseFloat(amount.getText().toString()) * cfRate)));
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getView().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            db.close();
        }
    });
```

I keep getting the error at this line:

```
Float cfRate = c.getFloat(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(lRate));
```

Comment: are you sure the cursor has information returned by the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tables other than `AUD` are empty, so you get an error telling you that no item could be found. You need to populate those tables with data if you want them to work.

Comment: wow you were right...every other table was indeed null. populated the tables and everything is working as intended.